# Iframe's width and height applying to its parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a simple HTML page. Inside that an **accessible (same domain)** `iframe` exists which contains some simple text and images.

Upon **zoomin** and **zoomout** button click i am scaling the `iframe`'s body with css's `transform: scale(n)` property.

Now my query is how to remove the `scroll` of the iframe (both horizontal and vertical) and add the same to parent (`body`), to make the user think that there is no `iframe` at all and scroll will be with main `body`.

I have created a example. Can someone suggest me the fix, as there are zoomin and zoomout based issuse which I can see on the height fixing. I found a method called **`getBoundingClientRect()`**.

ref: http://plnkr.co/edit/PJJ9lN1BJywFNLFXzcBB?p=preview

Comment: Set `overflow: hidden` to `body` within the `iframe`, and zoom `frameElement` instead of the content.

Comment: The scaling is done by css `transform`, and i cannot get the actual _height_ inside the `iframe`. `iframe body`'s  `overflow: hidden` is already there. thats how i have to show parent body's scroll instead of `iframe`.

Comment: Then do exactly what I've proposed in my comment, that works.

Comment: And @Teemu, please have you tried scaling a iframe?